# A few questions regarding a simple c programming code

Tags: c

I've just recently started learning c programming at my school and have already stumbled upon simple obstacles. I call it simple because I can sense the solution being right there but just can't seem to get it to work.

Question 1: I'm trying to have a person input 2 variables, one for X and one for Y. I've learned to use `char c; c = getchar();` and `scanf_s("%d", &n);`

I am wondering if I could use any of these two to make a person able to input 2 different variables for X and Y. I've also seen online that sometimes people are asked to input: x y( with a space in between) and the code will then recognize the first input as x and the input after the space to be the y.

The second question is that I tried using the command `x>>31` to show the 32bit binary code of value x, but the output I get is 0. Any clue on how to fix that? for example I have a line of code that is: `printf("%d & %d = %d %d\n", num1, num2, result1, result1>>31);` but the last %d shows `0` instead of the 32bit binary code of `result1`.[picture of my code and the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rfUf.png)

Comment: Please put your code + in/output in your post.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text

Comment: We need you to post each of these two questions separately.  The short answer to question 1 is "don't use any of those, use fgets and strtok, if your instructor hasn't taught you about fgets already they are teaching C Wrong™".  The short answer to question 2 is "the correct way to do that is `printf("%08x\n", x);` and `x>>31` does something completely different, not at all what you want."  The long answer to each is several paragraphs long and we want them to be findable separately by future people having the same problems.

Comment: For Q1: What is it you want the user to input? Their age? gender? name? income? That's really important cause the way to do it depends on that. BTW: On terminology: A user **don't** inputs variables. A user inputs values that your program stores in appropriate variables.

Comment: Hello, thank you all for the quick replies. I apologize for the lack of information on my question. I definitely should have paid more attention on how to post here. I will edit my question to make it make more sense.

Comment: For Q2: What do you mean by "the 32bit binary code of ..."? You do know that `>>` is a shift operator, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Re: scanf, I suggest reading the documentation for the function. This page is for Visual Studio 2015 but the examples should help you whichever IDE you're using:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

You are misunderstanding what the ">>" operator does. (result1>>31) will shift result1 right by 31 bits. This will result in 0 for a 32 bit value unless it is unsigned and very large (more than 2^31, which is around 4 billion, in which case it will result in 1) or signed and negative, in which case I believe it resolves to -1.

You can use >> to show the binary representation of a number, but you'll need to use it several times to extract each bit. The 0 you're seeing is the first bit of the 32 bit value.

I would suggest you start by outputting each bit on a separate line, so that you can see what the code is doing, before outputting them concatenated together into a single 32-digit number.

Comment: Quote: "signed and negative, in which case I believe it resolves to -1" Well, maybe... According to the standard it is implementation defined so you can get any value.